# How to append pandas dataframe in a for loop while makeing cumulative sum on the first column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have several tabulated data files in a particular order, each consisting of three column (time, signal1 and signal2). I want to read all files from a folder in a for loop and create a pandas dataframe.
My issue is the following: the time should be recalculated after the first file is read based on the last element of the previous time. See below example:

File 1:

| Time | Signal1 | Signal2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.8 | 111 | 222 |
| 1.3 | 111 | 222 |
| 1.7 | 111 | 222 |

File 2:

| Time | Signal1 | Signal2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.2 | 111 | 222 |
| 1.5 | 111 | 222 |
| 2.4 | 111 | 222 |

File 3:

| Time | Signal1 | Signal2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.8 | 111 | 222 |
| 1.4 | 111 | 222 |
| 2.8 | 111 | 222 |

What I want to achieve

| Time | Signal1 | Signal2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.8 | 111 | 222 |
| 1.3 | 111 | 222 |
| 1.7 | 111 | 222 |
| 1.9 | 111 | 222 |
| 3.3 | 111 | 222 |
| 5.7 | 111 | 222 |
| 6.5 | 111 | 222 |
| 7.9 | 111 | 222 |
| 10.7 | 111 | 222 |

**What I tried:**
I tried pd.append, but with this option my time is not recalculated. I also tried to calculate the time column separately and later insert it back into the data frame, but was not successful.

```
for i in range(len(filenames)):
    files = pd.read_csv(filenames[i], skiprows=(14), sep='\t', names=('Time', 'Signal1', 'Signal2'))

    if i > 0:
        for j in range(len(files.Time)):
            data.Time.append([data.Time.iloc[-1] + files.Time.iloc[j]])

data = files
```

My files have different length and the difference in time is not constant.

Can anyone recommend how can I read and append my files with a recalculated time?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow !! Please reformat the dataframe you have mentioned in a proper way so that it is easier to understand. Also post the code snippet that you have tried and the issue you have faced.

Comment: You need to set `df.index = np.arange(len(df))+1` after concatenating the dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concat your dataframes read from csv and then assign an increment list to `Time` column.

```py
dfs = []

for i in range(len(filenames)):
    df = pd.read_csv(filenames[i], skiprows=(14), sep='\t', names=('Time', 'Signal1', 'Signal2'))
    dfs.append(df)

df_ = pd.concat(dfs)
df_['Time'] = range(1, len(df_['Time'])+1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes this works, but my problem is that my time is not constant between the measurements of the signal. However I can use your suggestion until I find a way to recalculate the time.

Comment: @Alfonso How do you re-calculate the time?